# Change navbar logo padding

Tags: css, navbar, padding

I was trying to style logo with padding and yellow background (similar to [vox.com](https://vox.com) website).

The vox website has navbar logo with yellow background and padding:

```css
padding-top: 8px;
padding-right: 16px;
padding-bottom: 8px;
padding-left: 16px;
```

This make it create a cool effect with the logo appearing to protrude to body section.

I was trying to create the same effect on the site [raachotrekkers.com](https://raachotrekkers.com), but it did not happen.

The Vox site is using an SVG logo, whereas I'm using a PNG image.

Is this the reason?

Comment: Can you share the code that shows your attempt done so far?

Comment: your logo in  raachotrekkers.com is on the top centre of the navbar. So can you elaborate on what you trying to achive?

Comment: I want to move it to the left and style it like the Vox.

Comment: @MohitMaroliyaB17CS036 I added padding to the custom-logo-link class

Comment: @PawanRanta Great but try to add the complete code so that we can help you in a better way? The code you have added is showing nothing. If it not resolved add the code please?

Comment: @ækit Postitioning the logo to the left is doable from the theme settings but it is the style that I'm unable to figure out.

Comment: @MohitMaroliyaB17CS036 I had added the code through additional css (Wordpress dashboard>>Appearance>>Customize). 

.custom-logo-link
{
padding-top: 8px;
padding-right: 16px;
padding-bottom: 8px;
padding-left: 16px;
}

Comment: hey, @PawanRanta check my answer & tell me if this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using `position:absolute;` and then `top:0;`

here is the code

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
nav{
  padding:0 10%;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  min-height:50px;
  max-height:80px;
  box-shadow:0 2px 10px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 16%);
}
.brand{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
}
.navlogo{
  width:180px;
}
.rightele{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:right;
  width:100%;
}

.rightele>*{
  align-items:center;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
}
.rightele ul li{
/*   padding:5px 10px; */
   list-style-type: none;
}
.rightele ul li,
.rightele button{
    margin:5px 10px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.rightele button{
  height:40px;
  padding:5px 10px;
  color:white;
  font-weight:800;
  background-color:#161616;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="brand">
    <img class="navlogo" src="https://mlmgm6ui7ujb.i.optimole.com/Z_NXo3Y.9AP_~52a37/w:auto/h:auto/q:85/https://raachotrekkers.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/Raacho-Trekkers-Logo.gif">
  </div> 
  <div class="rightele">
    <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>About Us</li>
      <li>Blog</li>
      <li>Road Trip</li>
    </ul>
    <button>TALK TO US</button>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I did not add CSS for the mobile view because you probably want a burger icon over there and hide all options.

So open this in full screen

Answer (score 1):

I hope you can get some reference from here:

[codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-montalcini-hgldw?file=/index.html)

Also added the code

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/styles.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <img src="logo.png" alt="logo" />
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background: #dedede;
  padding: 48px;
}

img {
  width: 112px;
  height: 60px;
  background: yellow;
  padding: 12px 22px;
}
```

> You can download the png file of logo from [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=transparent%20vox%20logo%20svg&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwj9wY7X84r1AhUP_TgGHVV0BZUQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=transparent%20vox%20logo%20svg&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzoHCCMQ7wMQJzoFCAAQgAQ6BggAEAgQHjoECAAQHlD8AVj8FGDrF2gBcAB4AIABhgOIAeUPkgEHMC4zLjIuM5gBAKABAaoBC2d3cy13aXotaW1nwAEB&sclient=img&ei=rlLNYf2yMI_64-EP1eiVqAk&rlz=1C1GCEV_enIN962IN962#imgrc=V_DK1EMLCZvWtM)

Comment: Thank you but it did not work.  The Vox site has  

.c-global-header__logo   
{
background: #fff200;  
**margin-bottom: -15px;**

}

I this is responsible for the extending logo effect.

Comment: @MohitMaroliyaB17CS036 you can't ask someone to accept your answer if they already said it did not work. always ask with `if it helps` or `if it answers`.